# Powershell Help: Add "Domain Admins" to NTFS Full Control Permission to all File Shares?

Tags: powershell, server, permissions, ntfs, fileshare

I am trying to the Domain Admins group to all the file shares on our server with Full Control NTFS permissions, but it seems to lock up and cant proceed at the "$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)" line.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
$shares = Get-SmbShare

foreach($share in $shares) {
    $Acl = get-acl $share.Path

    $Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Domain Admins", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)

    Set-Acl $share.Path $Acl
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this isnt working? I was able to add Domain Admins to File Share Permissions but cant seem to do the same with NTFS permissions following the same algorithm.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the script as a Domain Admin?

Comment: What error you have received ? define "lock up" please.

Comment: @scepticalist, yes and have also tried as local administrator.

Comment: @Ranadip Dutta, when I say lock up, I mean the script doesn't finish the loop and proceeds to the next object. It just hangs forever at the line of code I mentioned up top.

Comment: You need to debug it. You need to see on which of the shares it is causing that behavior. Isolate it first. If possible, log it to understand it better.

Comment: How can I do that? It hangs on the very first loop. Could it be possible that it hangs because Domain Admins already exists as an ACE for that fileshare? if so, how can I check if Domain Admins does not exist, then add?